# Is there a way to save Android's Bitmap with ALPHA_8 config as a grayscale JPEG image?

Tags: android, bitmap, grayscale

I have been trying to save a bitmap as grayscale. The configurations provided by android to store single channel color seems to be only `ALPHA_8`. When trying to save bitmap in `ALPHA_8` as JPEG by calling `Bitmap.compress` function, I get blank image. What is the correct way of saving grayscale image in android?

Please note that my concern is about storage requirement. I just want to save a single channel(grayscale) JPEG. Making `R==G==B` in `ARGB_888`format does make it grayscale but the color information saved by `Bitmap.compress` still seems to be 3 channel.

Comment: ALPHA_8 stores the data as a transparency channel, useful for some effects.  It's not meant for grayscale.  You still want to use ARGB_8888, you just want to make sure that R==G==B for each byte so its gray

Comment: My primary concern here is storage requirement. When saving using Bitmap.compress, what ensures that it is saved as only single channel? Setting R == G == B, does make it gray but does it save as single channel as well?

Comment: And it should be added that closing this question was in error. It's _not_ a duplicate of the mentioned one at all. This is still a valid question with no apparent answer other than "bring your own code to save it for yourself".